# How to open a new terminal and run commands from an already active shell file

Tags: linux, shell, raspberry-pi

I am fairly new to Linux, so if I am referencing something with the wrong wording please let me know!

I have created the following shell file, which works perfectly:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd ~/Desktop/folder/
cd companion && npm start

The lines I want to add below:    

Opens New Terminal with the following:
cd ~/Desktop/folder/
cd javaclient && mvn exec:exec
```

When I execute this shell file it works fine and runs my app, however I want to add some lines in there that would open a new terminal window ('lxterminal' works for me) and run a few commands that would start running another app. Does anyone know how I can accomplish this? Any help/suggestions will be much appreciated!

P.S. The whole idea is to run 2 apps in 2 separate terminal windows by only executing 1 shell file.

Comment: Do you _really_ need a terminal to interact with both of the programs? Unless you do, look into launching one or both of the applications in the background, using an ampersand (&), possibly redirecting the output and add a "wait" at the end.

Comment: Yes, I am afraid... I just set up the alexa sample project https://github.com/alexa/alexa-avs-sample-app/wiki/Raspberry-Pi, and I am trying to automate the commands needed to start alexa.

Comment: @asleniovas : Can you try using my solution below and replace the script with the command you intend to run or add the commands you want to run within the script?

Comment: I am fairly new to Linux, therefore I can't fully understand you suggestion, sorry. I will edit my script please see above.

Comment: @asleniovas : Create a script of the same name with she-bang as #!/bin/bash, make it executable as chmod +x somescript.sh and add the contents as cd ~/Desktop/folder/ cd javaclient && mvn exec:execcd ~/Desktop/folder/ cd javaclient && mvn exec:exec

Comment: Okay so I've got that created with all the content. Do I need to open a terminal and type your method as in --title="MyScriptWindow" \ -e "bash -c ./myfile.sh;bash"\  now?  Sorry for the noob questions..

Comment: @asleniovas : No the lxterminal is just a command you can use your in original script or in the command line directly. Add the line to the original script

Comment: @Inian I've added your method lines to my shell file alongside the commands I want to execute, and when I run by typing sh myfile.sh it just errors with lxterminal--title=Hello: not found and cd: can't cd to companionservice. I think I might be writing it wrong, would you kindly give an example with my script example?

Answer (score 1):

You can use built-in [`lxterminal`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/lxterminal.1.html) programatically as,

```
lxterminal\
    --title="MyScriptWindow" \
    -e "bash -c ./somescript.sh;bash"\
```

`bash` is triggered manually at the end to prevent the terminal from closing, after the command or the script completes.

Comment: Good, but in general if you omit the "-c" it would search the current directory, then $PATH.  I usually end with something like:  *read -p "Press ENTER to close the terminal"*

Comment: Actually you can use any terminal emulator, e.g. `xterm` or `gnome-terminal` or `xfce4-terminal` or `x-terminal-emulator` instead of `lxterminal`